# Salesforce1 : Report navigation with url parameters not working

Tags: filters, salesforce1-platform, custom-reports

I need to filter the records display on report according to the logged in user. Therefor I am using URL parameters as, (which works fine on SF classic)

```
/{REPORT_ID}?pv0={LOGGED_IN_USER_NAME}
```

But this approach is not working on Salesforce1 as it is not supporting URL hacking.

How can I load a standard report on Salesforce1, by feeding the logged in user into its filter?

Comment: Still not available, you'll have to vote for this [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DjkfAAC)